# searching a div inside each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to search items from a div. Currently all items are displayed i have placed a drop down for searching. If the user selects from a drop down value is passed into the j query function, on the basis of that value i have created an array inside the j query function now i want if the user selects the first option from the drop down whose value is 1. Searched should be performed on the basis of that array all elements inside that array should be searched from a specific div. All those searched items should be displayed and all other should be hidden Any help???
Here is my code...

```
    <div class="searched">
                            <?php       
                            $this->load->view($this->uri->segment(1).'/blocks/'.$block_name);
                            ?>
</div>

if (val == 1){

    var test = ["optics", "displays", "Consumer Goods"];

        $(test).each(function( index, value ) {

            var search =  value;

        });
```

Comment: describe more correctly what exactly you want

Answer (score 0):

maybe somthing like this you need? i understand the div is into a loop.

```
<div id="<?php echo $block_name; ?>" class="searched" style="display: none;">
<?php       
 $this->load->view($this->Uri->segment(1).'/blocks/'.$block_name);
?>
</div>
<div id="<?php echo $block_name; ?>" class="searched" style="display: none;">
<?php       
 $this->load->view($this->Uri->segment(1).'/blocks/'.$block_name);
?>
</div>



</body>
</html>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var display='<?php echo $block_name ?>';
var test = ["optics", "displays", "Consumer Goods",'block_name'];

        $(test).each(function( index, value ) {
            var search =  value;
            if(search == display){
                $('#'+search).show();
            }
       });
})
</script>
```